# RegEx with \d doesn’t work in if-else statement with [[

Tags: command-line, bash, scripts, regex

i wrote the following script. It will be used in a build process later. My goal is to decide whether it's a pre release or a release. To archive this i compare $release to a RegEx. 
If my RegEx matches it's a pre release, if not it's a release.

```bsh
#/bin/bash
release="1.9.2-alpha1"
echo "$release"
if [[ "$release" =~ \d+\.\d+\.\d+[-]+.* ]];then
echo "Pre"
else
echo "Release"
fi
```

But as result i always end up with the following:

```
~$ bash releasescript.sh
1.9.2-alpha1
Release
```

Version:

```
Ubuntu 18.04.1 LTS
```

I used this [editor](https://www.regextester.com/97945) to test my RegEx. I'm stuck for at least 6h, so i would appreciate some help greatly.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

`\d` and `\w` don't work in [POSIX regular expressions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression#POSIX), you could use `[[:digit:]]` though

```
#/bin/bash
release="1.9.2-alpha1"
echo "$release"
LANG=C # This needed only if script will be used in locales where digits not 0-9
if [[ "$release" =~ ^[[:digit:]]+\.[[:digit:]]+\.[[:digit:]]+-+ ]];then
echo "Pre"
else
echo "Release"
fi
```

I have tested this script, it output "Pre" for given $release

Checked out your regex builder, it works only with perl compatible and javascript regex, while you need posix, or posix extended.

By [@dessert](https://askubuntu.com/users/507051/dessert):

> `[0-9]` is the shorter alternative to `[[:digit:]]`. As the beginning
>   of the string is to be matched, one should add `^`, while `.*` at the
>   end is superfluous: `^[0-9]+\.[0-9]+\.[0-9]+-+` – using a group this
>   can be further shortened to: `^([0-9]+\.){2}[0-9]+-+`

Comment: Beat me to it! Also, fwiw if you'd used `shellcheck` then it has a warning "SC1001: This \d will be a regular 'd' in this context.", which is quite helpful. [Other answers](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/421460/bash-regex-and-https-regex101-com).

Comment: Is [0-9] equivalent to [[:digit:]] though? I was under the impression that POSIX character classes match Unicode characters, so could very well match digits in languages that don't use 0-9.

Comment: @Fax Not sure about [0-9] but [A-Z] match unicode characters, the way to change that is only set locale by `LANG=C`

Comment: @Fax "Is [0-9] equivalent to [[:digit:]] though?" TIL that the answer is [no](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/414226/difference-between-0-9-digit-and-d).